# App installed on OpenShift won't run after adding form

Tags: python, flask, openshift, setup.py

I added a form to my application using WTForms, and now my app no longer works on OpenShift.  I can run it on localhost, so I believe the error may lie in `setup.py`.  What do I need to change to get this to work?

```
from setuptools import setup

 setup(name='Granite',
     version='2.0',
     description='Personal blog',
     author='myname',
     author_email='myemail',
     url='mysite',
     install_requires=[
         'Flask',
         'Flask-FlatPages'
     ],
 )
```

Comment: What does `$ heroku logs` tell you?

Comment: @IanAuld I'm not deploying it in heroku

Comment: So how are you deploying it? And what errors are you getting? 500 is a server error letting the client know something went wrong with the app. You should be able to see what exactly went wrong somehow.

Comment: Creating a setup.py file has nothing to do with Flask and the guide you linked makes no mention of it.

Comment: @IanAuld I'm using openshift. I encounter none errors in localhost, so i imagine there is something wrong with my dependencies with i deploy it.

Comment: @IanAuld this was the original source i checked to make the blog https://riccardo.forina.me/recycling-part-2/

Comment: You probably need to add `flask-wtf` to your `install_requires` list since it seems Openshift uses a `setup.py` instead of a `requirements.txt` although I have read that much in to it.

Comment: Reading more in to it it looks like they do make use of `requirements.txt`. I would suggest doing a `$ pip freeze >  requirments.txt` and forgoing the `setup.py` as it would be redundant at that point.

Comment: @IanAuld dude that was it. Please make an answer to accept it! I mean the flask-wtf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `flask-wtf` to your `install_requires` list.

`setuptools` uses this list to install whatever packages your application need to run. It's important to keep it updated. You can see what packages you have installed in you virtualenv (you *are* using a virtualenv right?) by runnning this command from your terminal with the virtualenv active:

`$ pip freeze [> filename]`

The part in the brackets can be optionally added to output the results to a file (usually called `requirments.txt`). Note that you will likely see some things in `pip freeze` you don't remember installing. These are packages that are installed via the `requirments.txt`/`setup.py` of the package syou did install. Off the topp of my head just installing flask your freeze should have `wsgiref`, `jinja2`, `werkzeug` and I think one more.

Some references:

- [requirements files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_freeze.html)
- [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_freeze.html)
- [setuptools](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#basic-use) (for setup.py)